# JsonNode in JSON in Rust

Tags: json, rust

I ran through the standard JSON library of Rust http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/json/ and couldn't figure out what represents a node in it. In Java it's `JsonNode`. What's it in Rust? For example, how can I pass an argument of the type `JsonNode` in Rust?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust's "DOM" for JSON is defined by [`Json`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/json/enum.Json.html) enum. For example, this JSON object:

```
{ "array": [1, 2, 3], "submap": { "bool": true, "string": "abcde" } }
```

is represented by this expression in Rust:

```
macro_rules! tree_map {
    ($($k:expr -> $v:expr),*) => ({
        let mut r = ::std::collections::TreeMap::new();
        $(r.insert($k, $v);)*
        r
    })
}

let data = json::Object(tree_map! {
    "array".to_string() -> json::List(vec![json::U64(1), json::U64(2), json::U64(3)]),
    "submap".to_string() -> json::Object(tree_map! {
        "bool".to_string() -> json::Boolean(true),
        "string".to_string() -> json::String("abcde".to_string())
    })
});
```

(try it [here](http://is.gd/W7gYJv))

I've used custom map construction macro because unfortunately Rust standard library does not provide one (yet, I hope).

`Json` is just a regular enum, so you have to use pattern matching to extract values from it. `Object` contains an instance of [`TreeMap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.TreeMap.html), so then you have to use its methods to inspect object structure:

```
if let json::Object(ref m) = data {
    if let Some(value) = m.find_with(|k| "submap".cmp(k)) {
        println!("Found value at 'submap' key: {}", value);
    } else {
        println!("'submap' key does not exist");
    }
} else {
    println!("data is not an object")
}
```

**Update**

Apparently, `Json` provides a lot of convenience methods, including [`find()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/json/enum.Json.html#method.find), which will return `Option<&Json>` if the target is an `Object` which has corresponding key:

```
if let Some(value) = data.find("submap") {
    println!("Found value at 'submap' key: {}", value);
} else {
    println!("'submap' key does not exist or data is not an Object");
}
```

Thanks @ChrisMorgan for the finding.

Comment: how do I check if "data" has a certain key and if it does - retrieve its value?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, I've updated the answer. However, this is just a regular enum, so if you have questions like this, you'd better read the [guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide.html), it explains how to work with them.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: [`json.find(&String)`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/json/enum.Json.html#method.find)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, that's great, I completely overlooked that `Json` has methods of its own! Only it seems that it is `&str`, not `&String`.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: yeah, it [just got changed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/18544).

Comment: Woah, I just like the `if let Some(value) = foo() { /* use value */ } else { /* None was returned */ }` syntax!